# Hierarchy as grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, hierarchy

### I have hierarchy:

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Value Value { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Value
{
}

public class StringValue : Value
{
    public string Str { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexValue : Value
{
    public ComplexValue()
    {
        Parameters = new List<Parameter>();
    }

    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}

/// Contains ComplexValue
public class ComplexParameter : Parameter
{
}
```

### And XAML with templates

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pc:Parameter}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Value}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pc:ComplexParameter}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            <ContentControl Margin="18,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Value}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pc:ComplexValue}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pc:StringValue}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Str}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
```

### This look like:

```
Param1         -Control----
Param2         -Control----
Complex1
  Sub Param1     -Control-
  Sub Param2     -Control-
```

Or image here: freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9d438f52e7.png

### Question

How to do indent only in left column (parameter names).
Something like this:

```
Param1         -Control----
Param2         -Control----
Complex1
  Sub Param1   -Control----
  Sub Param2   -Control----
```

Or image here: freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4ab3045b75.png

*Sorry, but I cannot add urls and images :(*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, this task does not have simple decision, because view model should provide information about level of node in hierarchy. If provide level to view model, I can use [this decision](https://web.archive.org/web/20130530185416/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/davids/archive/2010/04/17/hierarchical-grid-with-wpf.aspx).

Also intresting [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/if-it-walks-like-a-duck-and-talks-like-a-duck-it-must-be-a-treegrid-a-simple-xaml-only-treegrid-ui-for-wpf).